# Compare Two Tables And Output Difference - T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables shown below

Table A

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| fname | lname | email |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+-----------+-------+
| leavedate | email |
+-----------+-------+
```

I need to match emails in the tables and output the table below using T-SQL:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| fname | lname | email | leavedate |
+-------+-------+-------+------------+
```

Something similar to VLOOKUP in excel.

Could you please help to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like (untested):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A TA
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B TB ON TA.email = TB.email
```

This should work as you expect.

At least it correspond to the behavior of Excel's VLOOKUP

Answer (score 1):

For reference' sake, I wanted to point out that it depends on whether or not the two tables match completely. This code shows the different ways to approach those situations. There are better examples (I especially like the ones with Venn diagrams) but these might help in the current situation:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (fname NVARCHAR(20), lname NVARCHAR(20), email NVARCHAR(30))
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (leavedate DATE, email NVARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @TableA (fname, lname, email) VALUES
('Jim','Halpert','jimh@dundermifflin.com'),
('Pam','Beasley-Halpert','pamb@dundermifflin.com'),
('Michael','Scott','michaels@dundermifflin.com'),
('Toby','Flenderson','tobyf@dundermifflin.com')

INSERT INTO @TableB (leavedate, email) VALUES
    ('2010-05-04','tobyf@dundermifflin.com'),
    ('2008-03-14','rogerb@dundermifflin.com')

SELECT ta.*, tb.leavedate
    FROM @TableA ta
        LEFT JOIN @TableB tb
            ON ta.email = tb.email

SELECT ta.fname, ta.lname, tb.email, tb.leavedate
    FROM @TableA ta
        RIGHT JOIN @TableB tb
            ON ta.email = tb.email

SELECT ta.fname, ta.lname, COALESCE(ta.email,tb.email,''), tb.leavedate
    FROM @TableA ta
        FULL JOIN @TableB tb
            ON ta.email = tb.email
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)